# Python2.7　Opencv3.0　特徴点検出にて

Tags: python, opencv

Pythonを勉強している学生のものです。以下のサイトのサンプルを試そうとしたのですが[![画像の説明をここに入力][1]][1]
このようなえらーが出てしまい対策がわからず右往左往しています。numpy、scipy、matplotlib,cv2は入っていることを確認しました。
解決策を教えていただけませんか？

http://tatabox.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/07/28/055257

BLUEPIXY様
コメントありがとうございます。
当方このようなところでつまずく素人のためどう処置していいかわかりません。例等あればお願いしてもいいでしょうか？

argus様
コメントありがとうございます。
lena.jpgを用意しtest8.pyと同じ位置に保存しましたが画像のようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

皆様
ありがとうございます。BLUEPIXY様の言うとおり引数がひとつ抜けていました。
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img,kp,　\ここ,/　color=(0,255,0), flags=0)

おかげで勉強が進みそうです。ありがとうございました。

Comment: opencv よくわかりませんが、[drawkeypoints](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html#drawkeypoints) とエラーメッセージから必要な３番目の引数として必要な出力画像引数が抜けています。

Comment: こちらで試した所、おそらくカレントディレクトリに `lena.jpg` が無いのではないでしょうか…。有名な画像なので、そこら中に転がっています。`lena.jpg` を持ってきて実行すれば、[python+Opencvによる画像解析1（ORB特徴量）](http://tatabox.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/07/28/055257) にある様な画像が表示されます。

Answer (score 1):

PythonのAPIで見たら、

```
def drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, outImage, color=None, flags=None):
```

これに変更してください。

```
cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, img2, color=(0,255,0), flags=0)
```

結果はimg2です。